How can one Include ChartLegends in the BarChart Graphic Output (PDF)?
In following the example for a stacked bar chart, I am able to produce the graphic that I want.  However, when I attempt to print the graphic as a PDF file, I find the ChartLegends are not included in the output, even though they appear (albeit, not linearly which would be nice to correct) in the notebook output. That is, they fall outside the bounding box for the graphic. Running Vers. 14.0 on Windows 11 64 bit.
How can I force the inclusion of the ChartLegends into the output Graphic?
My code is as follows:
expenses = {"Insurance", "Landscaping", "Fees", "Supplies", "Postal", 
"Accounting", "Repairs", "Electricity", "Nat. Gas", "Telephone", 
"Water"}

data0 = {
  { 0.00, 349.44, 20.00, 0.00, 14.49, 152.00, 0.00, 92.38, 6.30, 
   64.35, 0.00} ,(*June 2023*)
  {0.00, 349.44, 0.00, 0.00, 14.49, 152.00, 0.00, 92.38, 6.30, 64.35,
   0.00}, (*July 2023*)
 {0.00, 349.44, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 131.78, 0.00, 110.13, 6.30, 64.35,
   1023.00}, (*August 2023*)
 {997.00, 349.44, 0.00, 0.00, 3.78, 370.00, 0.00, 122.83, 5.00, 
  64.35, 00.00}, (*September 2023*)
 {0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 41.37, 17.04, 224.00, 0.00, 64.78, 6.30, 64.87, 
  1668.00},(*October 2023*)
 {0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00 , 0.00, 128.00, 0.00, 38.73, 6.31, 64.87, 
  784.33},(*November 2023*)
 {0.00, 349.44, 0.00, 0.00, 176.00, 67.78, 587.50, 40.27, 6.32, 
  0.00, 834.14},(*December 2023*)
 {0.00, 387.66, 0.00, 0.00  0.00, 13.23, 120.00, 0.00, 37.10, 5.00, 
  142.76, 871.50},(*January 2024*)
 {0.00, 387.66, 5.12, 0.00, 0.00, 156.00, 0.00, 41.79, 6.32, 70.5, 
  1458.49},(*February 2024*)
 {0.00, 928.20, 0.00, 0.00, 5.12, 127.50, 0.00, 40.84, 6.32, 70.50, 
  512.56},(*March 2024*)
 {0.00, 775.32, 0.00, 0.00, 11.52, 153.00, 0.00, 41.72, 6.32, 70.31,
  530.33},(*April 2024*)
 {0.00, 387.66, 0.00, 0.00, 4.48, 204.00, 0.00, 47.39, 7.63, 70.31, 
  634.29},(*May 2024*)
 {0.00, 387.66, 250.20, 0.00, 5.12, 85.00, 0.00, 65.74, 6.38, 70.31,
  975.33}(*June 2024*)
 };
data1 = Quantity[#, "Dollars"] & /@ data0;

tooltipLabel[price_, {row_, col_}, ___] := 
 Row[{"$", price, " ", expenses}]

BarChart[Labeled[#, Total@#, Above] & /@ data1, 
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", Joined -> True, 
 ChartStyle -> {Gray, Green, Red, Yellow, Darker[Green], Purple, 
  LightPurple, Orange, Brown, LightBlue, Blue}, 
 ChartLegends -> Placed[expenses, Bottom], 
 ChartLabels -> {{Style["July 2023", Bold, 12], 
 Style["August 2023", Bold, 12], Style["September 2023", Bold, 12],
  Style["October 2023", Bold, 12], 
  Style["November 2023", Bold, 12], 
  Style["December 2023", Bold, 12], Style["January 2024", Bold, 12],
  Style["February 2024", Bold, 12], Style["March 2024", Bold, 12], 
  Style["April 2024", Bold, 12], Style["May 2024", Bold, 12], 
  Style["June 2024", Bold, 12]}, None}, 
  AxesLabel -> Style["US $", 12, Bold], BarSpacing -> {0, 0.1}, 
  ImageSize -> 1400, LabelingFunction -> tooltipLabel, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style["Homeowners Association Expenses (2023-2024)", "Title", 20, 
   Bold, Black]]


Try "Save As" to make the PDF, instead of printing to PDF. Or b=BarChart[....]; Export["test.pdf", b]

That worked.  Accepted.
